# Parallelize the export from BigQuery to local JSON file in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, google-bigquery

We have a table in BigQuery that we need to export into a local newline-delimited JSON file. Using BigQuery's export to GCS functionality is problematic as it converts integer types to strings, see [export bigquery data to cloud storage, the integer field changs to string format but float format stays as numeric format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597550/export-bigquery-data-to-cloud-storage-the-integer-field-changs-to-string-format)  and [How to preserve integer data type when exporting to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json) and I've tried it myself and the ints are lost. We've come up with the following solution, which maintains integer types, but is **very slow:**

**Currently working code**

```
bq = bigquery.Client()
our_query = "select * from our_project.our_dataset.our_bq_table"

results_row_iter = bq.query(our_query) # google.bigquery.rowIterator
counter = 0
with open('/tmp/output_file.json', 'w') as f:
    for row in results_row_iter:
        f.write(json.dumps(dict(row), default=str) + '\n') # dumps as ndjson
```

`our_bq_table` is 5GB in BigQuery, with 3.4M rows and ~100 fields, and the above for loop takes 90 minutes on our table. `our_bq_table` is partitioned on the integer column `confId`, and there are ~100 unique confId's in the table, with values 1 - 100. We would like to leverage the partition key + parallelization to speed up this process... somehow.

**pseudo-code of what we're going for**

```
bq = bigquery.Client()
base_query = "select * from our_project.our_dataset.our_bq_table"

all_conf_ids = range(1, 100)

def dump_conf_id(base_query, id):
    iter_query = f"{base_query} where confId = {id}"
    results_row_iter = bq.query(iter_query)
    counter = 0
    with open(f'output_file-{id}.json', 'w') as f:
        for row in results_row_iter:
            f.write(json.dumps(dict(row), default=str) + '\n') # dumps as ndjson

in parallel:
    for id in all_conf_ids:
        dump_conf_id(id)

# last step, perhaps concat the separate files into 1 somehow, assuming there are multiple output files...
```

This approach leverages the `confId` field so that our BigQuery queries remain small. I'm not quite sure how to implement this beyond the pseudocode, and am overwhelmed with figuring out multi-threading vs multi-processing vs other ways to parallelize in python. Our final output needs to be a single output file, the pseudo-code dumps into separate files but if we can dump into a single file in parallel that would be great too.

**Edit:** a key question we're trying to resolve before implementing a solution is *Should we use multiprocessing or multithreading for this*, given that **this** is dumping to a local .json in parallel...

Comment: Perhaps you could do the export to GCS by using the [TO_JSON_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937832/530160) function, which preserves types.

Comment: @NickODell this looks incredibly promising, I've tested in the BigQuery console and it does seem to work. However, after running `bq.query(our_query)` in python, I am struggling to save this into a JSON file. We are trying to avoid at all costs converting these results into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: We've tried `output = json.dumps(results_row_iter)` but receive error `TypeError: Object of type QueryJob is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two rules of thumb:

- In Python, you can use multithreading in cases where your program is largely IO-bound, but you must use multiprocessing if it is CPU-bound. This is because of Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython).
- You shouldn't mix multithreading and multiprocessing in the same program.

In this case, I would guess that your problem (exporting a JSON per each result) is CPU-bound, so I would recommend multiprocessing. Here's a code example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_jobs = 4
with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
    # call dump_conf_id on each member of all_conf_ids
    print(p.map(dump_conf_id, all_conf_ids))
```

> [...] but if we can dump into a single file in parallel that would be great too.

I wouldn't bother within trying to write them to a single file. Reading in the files and concatenating them is likely to be the fastest part of what you're doing. A quick benchmark shows this runs at about 780 MB/s:

```py
import subprocess

with open("output.json", "wb") as f:
    filenames = [f'output_file-{id}.json' for i in all_conf_ids]
    subprocess.check_call(["cat", *filesnames], stdout=f)
```